# Selection of variables from a Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, combinations, uniform-distribution

A question asks:

Random samples $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ have the probability density function

$f(x)=1, 0<x<1$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

They are sorted such that $X_{(1)} <X _{(2)}<...<X_{(n)}$. Find the probability density function of $X_{(k)}$.

The answer begins with $$f_{x_{(k)}}(x) = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} f(x)[F(x)]^{k-1}[1-F(x)]^{n-k}$$

It looks like a binomial distribution to me, but seems incredibly odd that in a binomial distribution, the Combination Function is $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$. Why then, would there be a $(k-1)!$ ? Also, why do I have to multiply in an additional $f(x)?$ into the entire function?

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: are they independent ? and what is $F$ ?

Comment: The factor $\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!1!}$ is a multinomial coefficient. Search for the derivation of the pdf of $k$th order statistic. See e.g. https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/Stat/StatLec6-10.pdf.

Comment: It should look like a beta distribution